Object filling incorrectly
I'm doing my UNI's basic programming course and haven't used turtle since high school, and I was wondering why exactly this shape is filling incorrectly. Pictures are attached as to how it fill, and how it should look.
Here is the code below:
How the Turtle is drawing the trunk:

How the trunk is meant to look:

from turtle import *
t = Turtle()

t.begin_fill()
t.circle(10, 90)
t.forward(20)
t.penup()
t.back(20)
t.circle(10, -90)
t.pendown()
t.forward(30)
t.circle(10, -90)
t.back(20)
t.right(90)
t.forward(10)
t.end_fill()

I'm not really sure how exactly I would go about fixing this issue.

Fills work like connect the dots--if you're drawing circles, they're probably creating some self-intersecting lines which aren't allowed in fills. You'll need to outline the shape.

Thanks, I'll probably just remake the trunk without using circles

The key here is to not back up over your drawing.  Fortunately, you can reorder your instructions to avoid backing up and do this in fewer steps:
import turtle as t

t.begin_fill()
t.forward(30)
t.circle(10, -90)
t.backward(20)
t.right(90)
t.forward(10)
t.left(90)
t.forward(20)
t.circle(-10, 90)
t.end_fill()

t.hideturtle()
t.done()


